# User Registration Moderate

Tags: plugin-development, users, user-registration

Currently there is no easy way to moderate user registration (I mean manually approved users) in WordPress. Am I correct?

But for one of my BuddyPress project, it is really needed manually moderate users.

I have checked a few plugins too, but still I could not find a good one.

So I thought to make some custom codes to do it.

These are the steps I am going to follow.

1. Create a new table called `wp_temp_users` with main fields like email, first name, username, password,  etc.
2. I will create a registration form and when submitting form `wp_temp_users` table will be filled.
3. All users in `wp_temp_users` will be displayed on admin panel and there is option to approve or reject.
4. If admin accepts I will create the user using `wp_insert_user` with details of  `wp_temp_users`.

Is there any problem in my method or is there more easy way to do what I am going to build? (In short, un-approved (rejected or pending) user should be almost a guest user, they should not be able to log also.)

---

Edit : I don't know that this part is off-topic. If it is off-topic feel free to remove this part. I use BuddyPress. So BuddyPress profile should be created only if Admin approve an account....

Comment: the easiest way is to create a new role like "pending user" and to give this role to all new registration. and after you can move the user to another roel to valdate it. and you can create a role "spam" to give to users which are not allowed to try a new registration

Comment: @mmm Still users can logging to system even I created role like 'pending user'????? I did not understand this part (you can create a role "spam" to give to users which are not allowed to try a new registration )

Comment: If you don't want to use roles, you don't need to create new tables. - Just use a custom post type and post meta where needed.

Comment: @Sunil Hmmm.. Good idea.... I think it is the best solution for me. It will save lots of time of me.